# Git command line push rejected while accepted from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, command-line

I have set up and configured git on my computer, copied the public key to the server.

My problem is that if I try to clone, push, etc using command line commands I get rejected: Permission denined (publickey).
In the meanwhile if I do the same using Git Repositories view in Eclipse, everything works against the same repository.
My understanding was that git command line and Eclipse Git uses the same configuration.

Anybody has suggestion why I get rejected from command line?

Thanks

Comment: Your git command line is probably unable to find your ssh keys. You need first to detail what system you are working on. Also, make sure that you use git bash on Windows and not standard Powershell.

Comment: Does it help? https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey